# Java Host System Architecture

Tags: java, hardware

In Java, how can I determine the system architecture of the host at run-time? With my current setup, Windows 7 x64, Java JRE 32-bit, Intel Xeon w/ Intel 64, the system properties that seem most obvious reflect the architecture of the Java VM.

```
System.getProperty("os.arch");
System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model");
```

Result:

x86

32

Comment: Shouldn't you aim to be platform specific? Or are you just trying to harvest information?

Comment: Is your actual question why the system property "os.arch" is "x86" and not "amd64"?

Comment: I believe that's a function of the fact that I'm running the 32-bit JVM on a 64-bit OS. The reason I need this information has more to do with exes installed separate the Java app. They can ship as 32 or 64-bit apps and the installation dir changes based on the architecture.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the [OperatingSystemMXBean](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html) by calling   ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean() and it will give you:

**String getName()**
Returns the operating system name. This method is equivalent to System.getProperty("os.name").

**String getArch()**
Returns the operating system architecture. This method is equivalent to System.getProperty("os.arch").

**String getVersion()**
Returns the operating system version. This method is equivalent to System.getProperty("os.version").

**int getAvailableProcessors()**
Returns the number of processors available to the Java virtual machine. This method is equivalent to the Runtime.availableProcessors() method.

**double getSystemLoadAverage()**
Returns the system load average for the last minute. The system load average is the sum of the number of runnable entities queued to the available processors and the number of runnable entities running on the available processors averaged over a period of time. The way in which the load average is calculated is operating system specific but is typically a damped time-dependent average.
If the load average is not available, a negative value is returned.

[See this page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html#getPlatformMBeanServer()) for some more details on available options. In addition most containers have more available options regarding the container.

Comment: How is this supposed to help the poster?

Comment: @jarnbjo Ism't the host asking how to find information on the underlying OS at runtime ? Then this answers the info you can get from the JVM in a portable manner. Could you explain what is wrong with the answer, or what I did not understand ?

Comment: @Romain Hippeau , resurrecting this because I was looking for the same info... a 32bit JVM on a 64bit OS produces "x86" or "i386" for these properties. The properties report the word-size of the JVM ... NOT the word-size of the underlying OS. I have not found a solution either that isn't platform ugly and/or platform specific.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a way to do this on Windows, but Windows is not one of our supported platforms. This tends to work on Linux/Solaris variants though I haven't tested many others than our typical deployment platforms.

I cannot easily reproduce the code for this so partial-pseudo code it is...

```
IMPORTANT: Fallback for ANY problem/exception, return "os.arch"
1) Check if System.getProperty("os.name") doesn't contain Windows
2) Exec "uname -p", capture the output
```

Answer (score 0):

The system property "sun.cpu.isalist" may give you some information about the processor architecture. Yet, in the Windows OS it just returns a useful value in the 64 bits JRE, which returns “amd64”. Unfortunately, in the 32 bits JRE this property returns: “pentium_pro+mmx pentium_pro pentium+mmx pentium i486 i386 i86”

I test it in a Windows 7 x64, Intel I7 with both JRE 1.6 (32 and 64 bits).